# Create a nullable object. Can it be done?

Tags: c#

I was trying to work on a project and I want a nullable property.

NullableClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class NullableClass
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public NullableClass()
        { }

        public NullableClass(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

MainClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        puplic int? Number { get; set; }
        public NullableClass? NullableClass { get; set; }

        public MainClass()
        { }

        public MainClass(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual studio gives the following error:

```
The type 'NullableClass' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
```

How can I make my property: NullableClass? NullableClass

when I google on it they don't say why this cannot be done but they also don't say how it can be done.

So my question is the following. 
Can I create nullable objects? 
Yes? -> How?
No? -> Why not?

Comment: Reference types are already _nullable_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class in C# is by default a nullable type. Since it actually is a pointer which can be set to null.

The other object type in C# is `Struct` which is not nullable and is handled with value instead of reference. Simple types like `int` and `bool` are structs. You can define an struct almost like a class.

Search more for `Struct` and you will see.

In your case you can have:

```
public struct NullableStruct
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And it will work fine with `NullableStruct?`

Comment: You can't define parameterless constructors for structs.

Comment: @Lee You can but you need to initialize all properties inside it with data.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I forgot about that C# also had structs xD

Comment: No you can't, your example won't compile even if you name the constructors correctly and assign `ID` in the `string` constructor.

Comment: But like Lee says, There can't be a constructor in a C# struct

Comment: @StuiterSlurf To be clear, Lee's comment that structs can't have *parameterless* constructors is right, but your comment leaves out that one word, making it wrong. Structs can have constructors, so long as those constructors have parameters.